# Javafx. Поставщик-Потребитель. Обновление таблицы из потоков поставщика и потребителя

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, tableview

Задача Поставщик-Потребитель. Идея такая, поставщик заполняет склад, а потребитель берет из склада.
При запуске потока Поставщика необходимо добавлять записи в TableView. Как реализовать?

Код потока Поставщика.

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

import static sample.Main.*;

public class Provider implements Runnable{

    static boolean isActive = true;
    private static int speed = 1000;
    private TableView<Object> producerTable;
    private TableColumn<Object, String> producerColumn;

    public void run() {

        try {

            while(isActive) {

                full.acquire();
                crit.acquire();

                data ++;
                providerList.add(new Object("Box"));
                producerColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
                producerTable.setItems(providerList);

                crit.release();
                empty.release();

                Thread.sleep(speed);

            }

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){System.out.print(e.getMessage());}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

C UI нужно работать в JavaFX Application Thread. Из другого потока можно выполнить код в UI потоке с помощью

```
Platform.runLater(runnable);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html

С таблицей можно сделать как в примере

```
private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
            new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
            new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
            new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
            new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));

...

table.setItems(data);

...

data.add(new Person(...));
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm

и вызывать

```
Platform.runLater(() -> data.add(new Person(...)));
```

Comment: Но это чисто в массив добавить, а именно в таблицу как?

Comment: @ЯрославШироков, Это модель для таблицы, таблица отслеживает изменения и апдейтит себя. Или вот так можно `table.getItems().add(...)`, что тоже самое. Вот чисто модель, реально говорю )

Comment: Окей, но куда и как это прописывать то?) В побочный поток?

Comment: @ЯрославШироков, Ну вот допустим по нажатию кнопки вы стартовали второй поток, где доступаетесь к данным по апи, и когда данные получили, то апдетите ui вот так `Platform.runLater(() -> table.getItems().add(new Person(...)));` таким образом код выполнится UI потоке.

Comment: Так, понял, но теперь новая беда, таблица обновляется только после остановки потока. Получается нужно постоянно приостанавливать его чтобы таблицу обновлять?

Comment: @ЯрославШироков, советую взять пример из документации https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm и доработать его под свою задачу.